# Regex for getting region and lang from url /xx/xx in two groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url structure where the first subdirectory is the region and then the second optional one is the language overide:

`https://example.com/no/en`

I'm trying to get the two parts out in a group each. This way, in the JS, I can do the following to get each part of the url:

```js
const pathname = window.location.pathname // '/no/en/mypage'
const match = pathname.match('xxx')
const region = match[1]   // 'no' or '/no'
const language = match[2] // 'en' or '/en'
```

I have tried creating multiple regexes with no luck in nailing all of my requirements below:
This is the closest I have come, but it is prune to error due to also matching "/do" from `/donotmatch` with the following regex:

`(\/[a-z]{2})(\/[a-z]{2})?`
The problem with this one is that it's also matching cases like `/noada`.
I then tried to match first two a-z and then followed by either a forward slash or no characters like this: `(\/[a-z]{2}\/|[^.])([a-z]{2}\/|[^.])?` I think I am not getting the syntax correct for the not part.

The regex I am trying to create has to pass these criterias in order not to break:

- /no - group 1 match(no), group 2 undefined
- /no/ - group 1 match(no), group 2 undefined
- /nona - no matches
- /no/en - group 1 match(no), group 2 match(en)
- /no/en/ - group 1 match(no), group 2 match(en)
- /no/enen - group 1 match(no), group 2 undefined
- /no/en/something - group 1 match(no), group 2 match(en)
- /no/en/jp - group 1 match(no), group 2 match(en) (jp is not going to be matched)

I feel I am really close to a working solution, but all my tries so far have been off in a slight way.

If the group part is not possible, I suppose also getting /xx/xx and then splitting by / is also an option.

Comment: Like `/\/([a-z]{2})(?:\/([a-z]{2}))?(?=$|\/)/`? See https://regex101.com/r/JVwNgC/1

Comment: Why not just use `split()` and test the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with an optional 2nd capture group:

```
\/(\w{2})(?:\/(\w{2}))?(?:\/|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aUSvry/1)

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `\/`: Match starting `/`
- `(\w{2})`: First capture group to match 2 word characters
- `(?:\/(\w{2}))?`: Optional non-capture group that starts with a `/` followed by seconf capture group to match 2 word characters.
- `(?:\/|$)`: Match closing `/` or end of line

Answer (score 1):

Follow each capture with `(?=$|/)`, which is a look ahead to assert that  what comes next is either end of input or a slash.

```
https?://[^/]+/(\w\w)(?=$|/)(?:/(\w\w)(?=$|/))?
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/tZonHDiyfbUoW2).

The second capture is wrapped in an optional non-capture group via `(?:…)?`

To be more strict to allow only letters, replace `\w` with `[a-z]` but `\w` may be enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this new way of getting the same result using the new [URL pattern API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_Pattern_API)

The API is quite new as in the writing of this answer, but there is a polyfill you can use to add support for it right now.

```js
const pattern = new URLPattern({ pathname: '/:region(\\w{2})/:lang(\\w{2})?' })
const result = pattern.exec('https://example.com/no/en')?.pathname?.groups
const region = result?.region // no or undefined
const lang = result?.lang // en or undefined
```

Solving the issue with trailing slash, one could replace the slashes with nothing before sending the "url string" to the exec method.

```js
// ...
const urlWithoutTrailingSlashes = 'https://example.com/no/en/'.replace(/\/+$/, '')
const result = pattern.exec(urlWithoutTrailingSlashes)?.pathname?.groups
// ...
```

I did not yet find a way to do the optional trailing slashes in the regex inside the pattern as the [limitations of lookaheads and ends with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_Pattern_API#regex_matchers_limitations). If anyone finds a way, please edit this answer or add a comment to it.